# Weighted shuffle distribution at specific index (formula)

Tags: python, algorithm, random, statistics, probability

What's the probability of finding element `A` at index `i` in array `R` after shuffling it with a random sampling algorithm? Is there a general formula for that?

Example:
Given array `['a', 'b', 'c']` and weights `[3, 2, 1]`:

```
p[a at 0] = 50%
p[a at 1] = 35%
p[a at 2] = 15%
```

I found this by making a simulation with thousands of shuffles.

The weighted sampling/shuffle algorithm: [http://utopia.duth.gr/~pefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf](http://utopia.duth.gr/%7Epefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf)

Comment: Can you provide the python code you're using to shuffle the array? The article you linked to describes two different methods of shuffling.